# Correctness of the Betweenness centrality formula

Tags: graphs, social-networks, network-analysis

> [Betweenness centrality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betweenness_centrality) is defined as the number of shortest paths that go through a node in the graph.The formula is:
>
> $$\sum_{s \neq v \neq t} \frac{\sigma_{st}(v)}{\sigma_{st}}$$
>
> Where $\sigma_{st}$ is the total number of shortest paths from node $s$ to node $t$ and $\sigma _{st}(v)$ is the number of those paths that pass through $v$.

However it doesn't seem to me that the formula calculates what is defined. Why do we divide by the total number of shortest paths between $s$ and $t$ each time? Shouldn't we just divide by $2$ to compensate the fact that  $s$ and $t$ will appear twice in different orders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose we want to quantify the extent to which $v$ is between $s$ and $t$.  There could be a few ways.

One way to describe that extent is the probability of passing through $v$ if we want to reach from $s$ to $t$ by a randomly-selected shortest path. Assuming each shortest path is selected with equal probability, we will get $\frac{\sigma_{st}(v)}{\sigma_{st}}$, where $\sigma_{st}$ is the total number of shortest paths from node $s$ to node $t$ and $\sigma _{st}(v)$ is the number of those paths that pass through $v$. In particular, the extent of $v$ between $s$ and $t$ is 0 if none of the shortest paths from $s$ to $v$ goes through $v$ while it is 1 if all of them must go through $v$.

Assigning the same weight to each pair of starting node and destination node, we can see that $\sum_{s \neq v \neq t} \frac{\sigma_{st}(v)}{\sigma_{st}}$ measure the extent in which $v$ is the center of betweenness.

[image]<sub>The graph is created by https://graphonline.ru/</sub>

If you use $\frac{\sigma_{st}(v)}2$ to quantify the extent to which $v$ is between $s$ and $t$, there is no problem if you just care about $v$ considering $s$ and $t$ as fixed. However, take a look at the above graph.

- How much is $v_3$ between $v_0$ and $v_4$? There are 3 shortest paths from $v_0$ to $v_4$, 2 of which pass through $v_3$. We get $\frac{\sigma_{v_0v_4}(V_3)}2 = 2/2=1$.
- How much is $v_5$ between $v_0$ and $v_6$? There is only 1 shortest path from $v_0$ to $v_6$, which passes through $v_5$. We get $\frac{\sigma_{v_0v_6}(v_5)}2 = 1/2=0.5$.

Since $1>0.5$, we would like to conclude that $v_3$ is more between $v_0$ and $v_4$ than $v_5$ is between $v_0$ and $v_6$. However, we can go to $v_4$ without passing through $v_3$ while we must pass through $v_5$ to reach $v_6$ by a shortest path. So $v_3$ should be less between $v_0$ and $v_4$ than $v_5$ is between $v_0$ and $v_6$. This simple example shows that it does not make much sense to divide by 2 or, in fact, any constant if we want to normalize the measurement.

#### Exercises

**Exercise 1.** What are the centers of the graph above in terms of the betweenness centrality? (Note there could be multiple centers.)

**Exercise 2.** Suppose we define the betweenness centrality of $v$ as $\sum_{s \neq v \neq t} \frac{\tau_{st}(v)}{\tau_{st}}$, where $\tau_{st}$ is the total number of distinct edges in the union of all shortest paths from $s$ to $t$ and $\tau_{st}(v)$ is the number of those edges that are also incident to $v$. Would you consider the above definition a better definition of betweenness centrality?

**Exercise 3.** Suppose we define the betweenness centrality of $v$ as  $\sum_{s \neq v \neq t} \frac{\rho_{st}(v)}{\rho_{st}}$, where $\rho_{st}$ is the total number of distinct edges in the union of all shortest paths from $s$ to $t$ and $\rho_{st}(v)$ is the number of distinct edges that are on a shortest path from $s$ to $t$ that passes through $v$. Would you consider the above definition a better definition of betweenness centrality?

Answer (score 3):

> However it doesn't seem to me that the formula calculates what is defined.

The formula is right. The betweenness centrality is a value in an interval $[0, \ldots, 1]$. Thus, if the betweenness centrality of node $v$ is equal to $1$, then all shortest paths between two nodes of this graph pass through $v$. I will explain the correctness of this summation below.

---

> Why do we divide by the total number of shortest paths between s and t each time?

You are developing a summation of the percentages. This is needed to ensure that this sum will never exceed $1$. Suppose that you have $m$ different $s$-$t$ pairs of vertices in your graph. Thus, $\sigma_{st} = m$ and your summation goes through all $m$ $s$-$t$ pairs.
One can note that the term $\sigma_{st}(v)$ on this equation is binary (the shortest $s$-$t$ path passes through $v$ or not). Thus, if all $s$-$t$ paths go through $v$, you will have $m \cdot \frac{1}{m} = 1$.

---

> Shouldn't we just divide by 2 to compensate the fact that s and t will appear twice in different orders?

Indirectly, you're right. This formula measures the percentage of the shortest $s$-$t$ paths that pass through node $v$. In fact, a simple optimization of this algorithm for undirected graphs is to consider only $s$-$t$ paths where $s < t$. However, you can't divide it by $2$.

---

Curiosity: The only graph topology who has a node with betweenness centrality equal to $1$ is a star graph, like the examples shown in the figure below.

[image: Examples of star graphs]

Comment: It looks like you confuse betweenness centrality of a node in a graph with the betweenness of a node between two nodes. [The former](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betweenness_centrality#Definition) might be greater than 1 before normalization.